# Basic Index Raising and Lowering Question

Tags: electromagnetism, general-relativity, metric-tensor, conventions

I am trying to understand the order of the indices when raising or lowering tensors.

For example, the [electromagnetic tensor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electromagnetic_tensor):
$$F^{\alpha \beta} =
    \begin{bmatrix}
    0 & -\frac{E_{x}}{c} & -\frac{E_{y}}{c} & -\frac{E_{z}}{c} \\
    \frac{E_{x}}{c} & 0 & -B_{z} & B_{y} \\
    \frac{E_{y}}{c} & B_{z} & 0 &  -B_{x} \\
    \frac{E_{z}}{c} & -B_{y} & B_{x} & 0 \\
    \end{bmatrix}
$$
When lowering the indices I have seen
$$F_{\alpha \beta} = \eta_{\alpha \mu} \eta_{\beta v} F^{\mu v}$$
and
$$F_{\alpha \beta} = \eta_{\alpha \mu} \eta_{v \beta} F^{\mu v}$$

Which is the right order of the indices on the second $\eta$? Does the index you want always go first or does it go in the index spot where you want it to end up after contraction?

Comment: Why do you think the order of the indices on the $\eta$ matters?

Comment: Both are correct and give the same result

Comment: Possible duplicate by OP: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/476673/2451

Answer (score 1):

The order of the indices on the Minkowski tensor doesn’t matter because it is symmetric. Personally, I prefer the first example where the contracted index is close to what it is contracting with.